# how can make scrollable divs or tables for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am in web dev the past 2 years or so. never had to deal with mobile.
lately i am required to develop some responsive templates for wordpress.
i managed to get many things working except tables.

My idea for responsive table solution was putting table's content inside a div that has overflow:auto. similarly to [datatable fixed columns](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/)

I've worked on this the past few hours thinking that scrolling on mobiles browsers is the same as computer browsers. I then check my mobiles to see if it works(gallaxy note/tablet- worked fine, iphone 4 s/ iphone 5 - didnt work).
Here is fiddle the i worked on  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yP83n/10/)

After I realized that normal jquery `scroll()` wont work i started reading about jquery for mobile i found the following:

```
element.on("scrollstart",function(){
    console.log("happening");
});
```

I tried that and still nothing.

My question is how would i handle scrolling on mobile browsers? and generally how should i approach developing for mobiles ? a guide ?article ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've read some more and tried different things none of which was stable or working on several different mobiles.

The reason i thought that `scrollstart` doesnt work because it works different then `.scroll()`.

`.scroll()` event fires every step of the scrolling giving better indication of whats going on whereas `scrollstart` fires only one time when you start scrolling and `scrollstop` fires when you stop scrolling and it seem to works just fine on iphone and android devices.

However when using start/stop there's still a gap that you cant account for.
I thought of 2 solutions for that:

1. at `scrollstart` I will start an interval that runs as fast as possible and will fire another event or perform an action - in my case update the header's left scroll and at `scrollstop` kill the interval.
2. at `scrollstart` bind document to `mousemove` and perform the action you like. at `scrollstop` unbind mousemove.

I think number 1 should work more reliably however will be heavier / require more resources.

```
var interval = "";
$('.element').on("scrollstart",function(){
    if(!interval){
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            //* fires event
            console.log($('.element').scrollLeft());
        }, 0);
    }
}).on("scrollstop",function(){
    console.log($('.element').scrollLeft());
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = false;
});
```

Hope that helps whoever had that problem.